# How to reduce jar size while using maven-assembly-plugin in pom.xml for building spark application

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using the below plugin: maven-assembly-plugin in my pom.xml file with many other separate dependencies mentioned in the same file as below to build a jar file for my spark application using IntelliJ:

**pom.xml**
*Maven-assembly-plugin*

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**pom.xml**
*other dependencies:*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-emr</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.125</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.106</version>
</dependency>
```

to name a few..............!

What's happening is, this maven-assembly-plugin is bundling in all the dependency jars together with the main jar file and the **size of the final jar file goes beyond 150+ Mb**.

Is there a way in which I can mention only a particular dependency from my pom.xml to be included in the final jar file and excluding all the other dependencies??

With only this dependency included in the jar, hopefully, the final jar size should come down below 1 Mb.

The specific dependency which I want to include in my final jar is the below one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20200518</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You know of maven scopes?

Comment: If you want to have only particular dependencies in your final jar you have to remove the dependencies (one option) the other option is to check which you really need to have in your jar vs. using at build time (scope: provided)... ?

Comment: @khmarbaise If I remove those other dependencies from the pom file....will there be any impact on how the application functions?

Comment: Also @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I am not aware of maven scopes!! Need to check it out

Comment: If you remove things of course... but the question is: Do you really need all given deps at runtime ? Maybe you only need them at build time? (scope: provided)